# How to connect to QLocalServer with posix socket on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, sockets

In my main application I create [QLocalServer (from Qt 5.5)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html):

```
  // socket_name = /tmp/my_programm_sock

  ... 

  QLocalServer::removeServer(socket_name);
  if (!server_.listen(socket_name)) {
    exit(1);
  }

  ....
```

Next, I have another one `C lang` app. I try to connect to this socket:

```
  int sockfd
  struct sockaddr_un;

  memset(&serv_addr, 0x00, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
  strncpy(serv_addr.sun_path, socket_name, sizeof(serv_addr.sun_path) - 1);

  servlen = sizeof(serv_addr);
  if ((sockfd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("Creating socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("Connecting");
    exit(1);
  }

  ...
```

But I keep getting an error: `Connecting: Operation not permitted`.

I tried to setup `chmod 777` to this socket, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: I wrote: `I tried to setup chmod 777 to this socket, but the problem is not solved.` Is it enough?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I'm blind today. :/

Comment: I still added `server_.setSocketOptions(QLocalServer::OtherAccessOption);` above server listen - doesn't work too

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?